# PHP within typescript file

Tags: php, typescript

I need to populate some typescript arrays with PHP array values. Here is how I do it:

Relevant portion of index.php:

```
<?
    require 'scripts/back_end/database_connection.php';
    require 'scripts/back_end/get_countries.php';
    require 'scripts/back_end/views/select.php';
    require 'scripts/back_end/views/view.php';

    $conn->close();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var allCountries = <? echo json_encode($allCountries, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
</script>
```

I would much prefer to add the `var allCountries =` javascript line to my typescript file within this function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allCountries = <? echo json_encode($allCountries, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
    var _searchFilterViewModel: SearchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel(allCountries, allCategories);
    var _searchFilterForm = $("#find-vegan-products-page").find("form")[0];
    ko.applyBindings(_searchFilterViewModel, _searchFilterForm);
);
```

However the PHP tags are only recognised in javascript files. Is there ay way to let the php be recognised in typescript files?

Comment: Suggested edit - Why edit my question to contain code that I am not using? If you think I should use the new code, then suggest that in an answer or comment and state why.

Comment: You are totally right. Please note that the suggested review must be approved by more that one user. I think the edit will be rejected. In addition, note that I have approved the edit by mistake (but I'm the only one): I have searched a way to undo it, but there is not, I'm sorry. If the edit will be approved, I will revert it to original post. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be possible to insert PHP inside TypeScript files because those files need to be compiled and PHP content is not valid TypeScript code.

You can always output even if there are build errors by setting `--noEmitOnError` to false, but that is not advised..